# How to use my pretrained LSTM saved model to make new classifications

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, lstm

I have a simple pretrained LSTM model builded with Keras and Tensorflow, I trained, compiled and fitted it, and make a test prediction with a simple sentence, and it works, then I saved my model using `model.save(sentanalysis.h5` and everything OK. Then, I loaded this model with `model.load_model()`, and it loads without error, but when I tried `model.predict()` I got an array with floats that doesn't shows anything related to the classes:

How can I use my pretrained model to make new classifications?
The dataset I use to train it is very simple, a csv with `text` and `sentiment` columns, nothing else.
Can you help me?
This is the code of the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nlp
import random
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

dataset = nlp.load_dataset('csv', data_files={'train':'/content/drive/MyDrive/Proyect/BehaviorClassifier/tass2019_pe_train_final.csv',
                                              'test': '/content/drive/MyDrive/Proyect/BehaviorClassifier/tass2019_pe_test_final.csv',
                                              'validation': '/content/drive/MyDrive/Proyect/BehaviorClassifier/tass2019_pe_val_final.csv'})
train = dataset['train']
val = dataset['validation']
test = dataset['test']

def get_tweet(data):
    tweets = [x['Text'] for x in data]
    labels = [x['behavior'] for x in data]
    return tweets, labels

tweets, labels = get_tweet(train)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000, oov_token='<UNK>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(tweets)

maxlen = 140

def get_sequences(tokenizer, tweets):
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(tweets)
    padded = pad_sequences(sequences, truncating='post', padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
    return padded

padded_train_seq = get_sequences(tokenizer, tweets)

classes = set(labels)
class_to_index = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(classes))
index_to_class = dict((v, k) for k, v in class_to_index.items())
names_to_ids = lambda labels: np.array([class_to_index.get(x) for x in labels])
train_labels = names_to_ids(labels)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 16, input_length=maxlen),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

val_tweets, val_labels = get_tweet(val)
val_seq = get_sequences(tokenizer, val_tweets)
val_labels= names_to_ids(val_labels)
h = model.fit(
     padded_train_seq, train_labels,
     validation_data=(val_seq, val_labels),
     epochs=8#,
     #callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=2)]
)

test_tweets, test_labels=get_tweet(test)
test_seq = get_sequences(tokenizer, test_tweets)
test_labels=names_to_ids(test_labels)
model.evaluate(test_seq, test_labels)

# This code works when I loaded the previos code
sentence = 'I am very happy now'
sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([sentence])
paddedSequence = pad_sequences(sequence, truncating = 'post', padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
p = model.predict(np.expand_dims(paddedSequence[0], axis=0))[0]
pred_class=index_to_class[np.argmax(p).astype('uint8')]
print('Sentence: ', sentence)
print('Sentiment: ', pred_class)
```

And this is how I save and load my model withouth loading previous code:

```
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/Proyect/BehaviorClassifier/twitterBehaviorClassifier.h5')
model = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/Proyect/BehaviorClassifier/twitterBehaviorClassifier.h5')

#### ISSUE HERE
new = ["I am very happy"]
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000, oov_token='<UNK>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(new)
seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(new)
padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=140)
pred = model.predict(padded)
```

And I get this:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
[[7.0648360e-01 1.1568426e-01 1.7581969e-01 7.2872970e-04 4.2903548e-04
  8.5460022e-04]]
```

I've reading some doc, but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from your model code, you have the following:

`tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')`

Presumably, you have 6 different sentiment classes.  The output you are seeing from your `model.predict()` are the probabilities that the input belongs to the corresponding class, i.e. 70.6% chance that the sentiment is class 0, 11.5% that the sentiment is class 1, 17.5% that the sentiment is class 2, etc.

So what is typically done to postprocess these results is take the largest probability as the prediction using `np.argmax(pred)`, which in the case you posted should give you `0`, which then can be interpreted as your model believes your tweet is 70.6% likely to belong to class zero.

Comment: I didn't notice that, my train dataset has only 3 sentiment classes: 1 (positive), 0 (neutral) and -1 (negative). So should I change that layer to 3, and also the activation fuction?  If so, which would you recommend?

Comment: Yes, the final dense layer should be equal to number of classes for a multi class problem, so you would change it to 3, and you can keep the same activation function, since softmax is appropriate for multi-class problems.

Comment: Now I got a new problem, the saved model always returns a high value for class 2 [Negative[, it doesn't matter what sentence I put, always says it's negative, but in training, it works much better, did `save()` function change something in my model?

Comment: mode.save() would not have changed it, but this is now a very specific question to your model, the data it was trained on, as well as what sentence you are testing it on. It’s tough to tell without seeing the whole model.

Comment: That's the whole model, it's very simple, the dataset consist in 3889 tweets in spanish with a column for each one's sentiment (-1:negative, 0:neutral, 1:positive), splited in 80% train, 10%validation and 10% test. It's nothing special. Maybe because there's no preprocessing for the texts?

Comment: At this point, you are asking a question that is really different from the initial question, which I think has been answered.  Why your model is not giving expected results is difficult to say without seeing the model and running tests, but the advice I can give is make sure the preprocessing and data that you are feeding the model for testing is exactly consistent with what was done prior to model training.